# PopupWindow Overlap With Virtual Keyboard

Tags: java, android, kotlin, popupwindow

I have some problem with showing `PopupWindow` which is the popup overlaps with the keyboard. here my result

[image]

Here my popup code:

```
class NoteHintList(val view: View, val listener: MenuDetailFragment.OnItemListClickListener?){
    var noteHintList: List<String> = ArrayList<String>()
    val popupWindow = PopupWindow(view.context)

    fun setNoteList(noteHint: List<String>){
        this.noteHintList = noteHint
    }

    // ============ TODO: Pop up note hint ================================================================
    fun popupWindow(): PopupWindow {
        val popUpContents = arrayOfNulls<String>(noteHintList.size)
        ArrayList(noteHintList).toArray(popUpContents)

        val listView = ListView(view.context)
        listView.adapter = noteHintAdapter(popUpContents)

        // set the item click listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            listener!!.onItemListClickListener(listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString())
        }

//        val params: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
//        params.setMargins(16,0,16,0)


        popupWindow.setFocusable(false)
        popupWindow.contentView = view
//        popupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT - 32)
//        popupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        popupWindow.setContentView(listView)

        return popupWindow
    }

    // ============ TODO: Popup list adapter for pop up ===================================================
    private fun noteHintAdapter(array: Array<String?>): ArrayAdapter<Any> {

        return object : ArrayAdapter<Any>(view.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array) {

            override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

                // setting the ID and text for every items in the list

                val text = getItem(position)!!.toString()
                // visual settings for the list item
                val listItem = TextView(context)
                listItem.setText(text)
                listItem.tag = position
                listItem.textSize = 22f
                listItem.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10)
                listItem.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                return listItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The popup will show when text changed. here my code

```
txtHint.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
     override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
         val text = txtHint.text.toString()
         if (Pattern.compile("^\\s+$").matcher(text).find() || text == "") {
             popupNoteHintList!!.setNoteList(noteHintAllList)
         } else if (text.split(",").size > 0) {
              val textSplit = text.split(",")
              val myData = noteHintAllList.filter { s ->
                   s.toLowerCase().contains(textSplit[textSplit.size - 1].toLowerCase().replace(Regex("^ | \$"), "")) &&
                   s.toLowerCase() != textSplit[textSplit.size - 1].toLowerCase().replace(Regex("(^ +)|( +$)"), "")
              }
         popupNoteHintList!!.setNoteList(myData)
         if (myData.size > 0) {
             popupNoteHintList!!.popupWindow().showAsDropDown(txtHint, 0, 0)
         }
     }
 }

 override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
     popupNoteHintList!!.popupWindow().dismiss()
 }

 override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
      popupNoteHintList!!.popupWindow().dismiss()
 }
```

})

How to make the popup not overlap with keyboard, maybe move to above `EditText` if overlap, but still under `EditText` if not overlap

So result seem like this:

[image]

Comment: Is this property can help `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`?

Comment: @ buzzingsilently: where I can set?

Comment: Activity property of AndroidManifest...

Comment: No, the popup still overlap

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Still nope, I just request to change design with my boss.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the soft keyboard in the `afterTextChanged` method, so that the keyboard is always hidden when your popup appears.

Within the `afterTextChanged` method, add the following to hide the keyboard:

```
val imm = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0) //Hide soft keyboard.
```

Comment: I think is very weird if a user typing then the keyboard is hidden, it just suggests so that user not typing so much, just click the suggest, but if a user still want to type, it's Okay

Comment: The keyboard would not be hidden when the user is typing per se, but once the user has finished typing. That way, just as the user is finished typing, the keyboard will be hidden and the popup can be shown. 
You could also add a delay for the keyboard to be hidden, if you like.